# Validation Viewstate error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error when I tried to call a `OnClick` in my form

**Error:** `Failed validation of viewstate MAC. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same <machineKey> validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate can not be used in a cluster.`

**Code-Behind**

`<form runat="server" id="form1">
    <asp:Button ID="btnImprimeBematech" runat="server" OnClick="btnImprimeBematech_OnClick" Text="Imprime Novo Bematech"  />
</form>`

I don't understand becaus in others thread here in StackOverflow, some solutions was the action in the `<Form>` tag, but I don't have any `action` in my form.

I tried put `EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableSessionState="False" EnableViewState="false"` in my `<%@ Page` but still the same error

Comment: Is your application `hosted by a Web Farm or cluster`? Or did you perchance recycle the application pool before clicking the button?

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi my application isn't hoste by a web farm or cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `machineKey` value has to be the same on all machines in a webfarm.

Link : http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx

You set this property on all pages not just one page

```
In web.config

<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
```

It is always advisable to go with specifying the custom key for encryption and decryption in web.config. This is because when you set the EnableViewStateMac value to false you expose your application to security threats. This is because validation of view state will not happen in this case.

```
<machineKey validationKey="<encryptionkey>" decryptionKey="<decryptionkey>" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto"/>
```